# How to run multiple tasks concurrently in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am using python3 and I want to execute multiple tasks concurrently, without one to wait for another. I want to achieve it using **asynchronous programming** in python (**NOT** USING MULTI PROCESSING OR THREADING).

NOTE: I tried python asyncio library but could not get what I wanted.

```
import time

def func1():
    print("This is the beginning of function 1.")
    func2()
    print("This is the end of function 1.")

def func2():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("This is Function 2.")

func1()
```

I have two functions func1() and func2(). I Want to call func2() function inside func1() and I do not want func1() to wait for func2() to finish.

Expected Result:

```
>> This is the beginning of function 1.
>> This is the end of function 1.
>> After 5 seconds: This is Function 2.
```

I need detailed answer with code. Thank You in advance.

Comment: @martineau I think there is nothing wrong with that question. I Searched for the solution and could not found one, that is why I posted it here. I don't know why you have down voted that question.

Answer (score 2):

Details are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)

```
import asyncio

async def func1():
    print("This is the beginning of function 1.")
    task = asyncio.create_task(func2())
    print("This is the end of function 1.")
    await task  # You should await end of function here

async def func2():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("This is Function 2.")
```

```
>>> asyncio.run(func1())
This is the beginning of function 1.
This is the end of function 1.
This is Function 2.
```

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński, I think the author is honest even if he doesn't post his attempts